# Why ResourceBundle.getBundle(String str) cannot find values from default properties file in Websphere

Tags: java, websphere

let's say if there are several properties file

```
captions.properties
captions_es_ES.properties
captions_cn_CN.properties
captions_th_Th.properties
```

Currently on Tomcat, if call

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("someCaption");
```

there is no problem to get properties value

However when deploy the application in Websphere, then if local is en_US and call the same above code then application always throw `MissingResourceException` but the same line works just fine on any other foreign locale.

And if I enforce a locale like Locale.ROOT, then of course it works, but I thought geBundle(str) method should by default check default properties no matter what

I can guarantee that "someCaption" exists in all language properties files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be the spec/expected behavior -- maybe your native environment varies between Tomcat and WebSphere startup?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String)

> Gets a resource bundle using the specified base name, **the default
>   locale**, and the caller's class loader.

You could check if `Locale.getDefault()` differs in the two environments.